# How do I get the windows regional location setting?

Tags: .net, windows

I can find lots of information on how to get the regional and cultural settings in .Net but none of these get the current LOCATION setting. Does anyone know how to do this other than using the new Location API (it needs to work on >= XP).

In case your unsure, the location is set in the regional settings in the LOCATION tab, not the Formats or Languages tabs.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [How to get/set current location in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085115/how-to-get-set-current-location-in-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Aha!  Finally found it:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a4bb7327-f9d3-4115-a455-f664a0818120

Required code from link:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

private const int GEOCLASS_NATION = 16;

//SYSGEOTYPE
private const int GEO_NATION = 1;
private const int GEO_LATITUDE = 2;
private const int GEO_LONGITUDE = 3;
private const int GEO_ISO2 = 4;
private const int GEO_ISO3 = 5;
private const int GEO_RFC1766 = 6;
private const int GEO_LCID = 7;
private const int GEO_FRIENDLYNAME = 8;
private const int GEO_OFFICIALNAME = 9;
private const int GEO_TIMEZONES = 10;
private const int GEO_OFFICIALLANGUAGES = 11;


[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int GetUserGeoID(int geoId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int GetGeoInfo(int geoid, int GeoType, StringBuilder lpGeoData, int cchData, int langid);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int GetUserDefaultLCID();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int geoId = GetUserGeoID(GEOCLASS_NATION);
  string friendlyName = GetGeoFriendlyName(geoId);
}


private string GetGeoFriendlyName(int geoId)
{
  int lcid = GetUserDefaultLCID();
  StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder(50);
  GetGeoInfo(geoId, GEO_FRIENDLYNAME, bldr, bldr.Capacity, lcid);

  return bldr.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetUserGeoID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318138%28VS.85%29.aspx) function will tell you. The managed equivalent appears to be [`CurrentRegion.GeoId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.geoid.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, that what I thought too, but this is also just based on the selected format, not the location.

Comment: I was fooled because XP puts the Location setting on the Language tab. (XP doesn't have a Locations tab.) `GetUserGeoID` appears to be the correct function, it's just the surfacing in C# that is not available.