# How to get/set current location in windows?

Tags: c#, windows, regional-settings

I need to be able to get/set current location in Win 7 (Control Panel -> Regional and Language -> Location):

[image: Win7: Control Panel -> Regional and Language -> Location]

`RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` doesn't work (can I use it in wrng way??)

The same with `CultureInfo`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need change location in programm?

Comment: Do you really need to modify the system settings or do you just need to control some culture specific formatting inside your application? From a user point of view I'd strongly object to an application that does tamper with the region settings of my machine.

Comment: I really have to change the setting in the picture. That's the REQ ;)

Comment: Related: [How do I get the windows regional location setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668782/how-do-i-get-the-windows-regional-location-setting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok you need to change windows register
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Geo
and there you need change 'Nation'

Comment: for example Ukraine=241, USA=244

Comment: Yep. I don't like the idea of using registry in this case. Thou if I don't find any better solution, I'd have to..

Comment: This may be useful:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374073.aspx

Also there is a function, something like: SetGeoId, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored in the registry. You need to overwrite these keys.

To know where it's stored in the registry reead this article: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/registry2/jsi-tip-0311-regional-settings-in-the-registry-

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
CultureInfo _CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");                
            Application.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(_CultureInfo);
            Application.CurrentCulture = _CultureInfo;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
System.Globalization.CultureInfo myCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");