# Wrong country code from CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, cultureinfo

I have a problem with CurrentCulture (C#, Windows Store App).

I need to get user country code (to set default country to my country ListView).

I used code:

```
string currentCountryCode = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;

if (currentCountryCode != null && currentCountryCode.Length == 5)
{
    currentCountryCode = currentCountryCode.ToLower().Substring(3);
}
```

My question is: Why I get wrong country code (I get "us", but I have Latvia in my computer regional settings)?

Comment: what service you are using to get country code and flage ?

Answer (score 0):

[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not give you the country that you are physically located in.  It gives you the culture you have selected.  The culture is in the "Formats" tab of the "Region and Language" dialog, not the "Location" tab.

If you really want the "Location" setting, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10085592/2394945
Unfortunately, it looks like you have to go to the registry to get it.